# Call intent in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-implicit-intent

How can I make `call` by pressing button? I get my number as a string from `EditText`. Here is my sample code:

```
String phone = editPhone.getText().toString();
btnPhone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                call();
            }
        });
public void call() {
    try {
        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse(phone));
        startActivity(callIntent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException activityException) {
         Log.e("myphone dialer", "Call failed", e);
    }
}
```

I added all `permissions` to manifest file.

but I am getting `NullPointerexception`

Comment: what is your specific problem?

Comment: my app crushes by null pointer exception. can you provide me sample source code to make phone calls??

Comment: Your code is fine, the null pointer is coming from what line? the "String phone" part?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This simple approach should work for you.

Ex.

```
public class CallActivity extends Activity{
   String phone = "";

   onCreate()
   {
        btnPhone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
            @Override 
            public void onClick(View arg0) { 
                phone = editPhone.getText().toString(); 
                call(); 
            } 
        });    
   }

   public void call() {   
            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);          
            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+phone));          
            startActivity(callIntent);  
   }
}
```

You might be using String variable `phone` out of scope.

Answer (score 11):

I think you missed the "tel:" part in the URI.

Replace the following..

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse(phone));
        startActivity(callIntent);
```

with

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL,Uri.parse("tel:"+phone));
       startActivity(callIntent);
```

or

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+phone));
            startActivity(callIntent);
```

Comment: but also, i have another question :)how i finish the call??it doesn't finish automatically...

Answer (score 5):

see below code it may help you.

for call

```
EditText num = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.number_edit);
String uri = "tel:" + num.trim();
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(uri));
startActivity(intent);
```

for open dialer

```
Intent dial = new Intent();
dial.setAction("android.intent.action.DIAL");
dial.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"));
startActivity(dial);
```

Comment: call end worked in my app. see if i use above code then phone dialer open and there is red button for end call. check it again.

Answer (score 3):

```
String PhoneNo="+923341234567"
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + PhoneNo));
startActivity(intent);
```

and add a permission in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse(phone));
startActivity(callIntent);
```

above is the only method you use for calling a phone number in android, when you click on the call button a 'dilerpad' activty is started with perpopulated phone number, and the call will go if you press the call button on the dialer pad.

Comment: you cant make call by directly clicking on the call button, in turn it should go to the dialer pad activity.

Comment: Actually you can, with the permission to call. There are 2 Actions, ACTION_DIAL & ACTION_CALL : Where action dial takes you to the dialer with the number and call sends the call out.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_CALL Read that.

Comment: @JoxTraex wait i wll check it out

Comment: in what place i must insert this intent?

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL,Uri.parse("tel:" +"93");
intent.setData(Uri.parse(uri));
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
EditText num = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.phone_number);
String uri = "tel:" + num.trim();
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(uri));
startActivity(intent);
```