# How to intent dialer call from service?

Tags: android, kotlin, service, phone-call, android-dialer

I am using this [this dialer example](https://github.com/arekolek/simple-phone) as basement.
I have added some service(foreground) from where i should dial a call.
How can i make it?

I have this in Service(onStartCommand)

```
    if (checkSelfPermission(this, CALL_PHONE) == PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        val uri = "SOMENUMBER".toUri()
        startActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, uri).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK))
    }
```

But i does not work in service.
Error log:

```
Process: *.*.*, PID: 2789
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service *.*.*.*.Service@ab2ea53 with Intent { cmp=*.*.*/.*.Service (has extras) }: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.CALL dat=PHONENUMBER flg=0x10000000 }
```

What should i do to make it work? And which ways are more right(if mays>1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"SOMENUMBER".toUri()`

should be

`"tel:SOMENUMBER".toUri()`

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_CALL

> Input: If nothing, an empty dialer is started; else getData() is URI of a phone number to be dialed or a tel: URI of an explicit phone number.

Other related questions:

[Call intent in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10510395/call-intent-in-android)

[Android Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15842328/android-intent-action-call-uri)